# POST request to `/authorizations` end point(github API) returns 404

Tags: python-3.x, github, authorization, python-requests, github-api

This is the code I am using:

```
end = "https://api.github.com/"
def create_token(end):
    username = input('Enter GitHub Username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass()
    auth = (username, password)
    data = {
        "scopes": ["gist"],
        "note": "gistey"
    }

    rq = requests.post(end + "authorizations/", json=data, auth=auth)

    if "X-GitHub-OTP" in rq.headers:
        otp = input("Enter 2FA code: ")
        rs = requests.put(end + "authorizations/", json=data, auth=auth,
                          headers={"X-GitHub-OTP": otp})

        return rs
    return rq

test = create_token(end)
```

I am trying to create a new access token for my application using Github API. But the response returns 404 status code. I've double checked the

- end point
- the keys in the `json` to be sent

I am yet to find what is causing it to return `404` status code. After all this I came to the conclusion that this can be problem at the GitHub's end. But it is too hard to believe that a website such good can make such a mistake.

Therefore, I am trying to know what is wrong in the code. Or is it a bug in GitHub's API.

Comment: You're trying to send two requests that should be bound with same session. Try to use `session = requests.Session()` and then send each request as `session.post(...)`, `session.put(...)`

Comment: Nah, doesn't work @Andersson But I really don't think that these two requests have to be in a session, they are completely unrelated.